How should I type a function that takes the return value of ArgumentParser.add_subparsers as parameter?
I'm type hinting a codebase that uses argparse to parse command-line arguments, and in this part of the code there are some functions that make operations on the value returned by argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers. I couldn't figure out what type this would return from looking at the documentation, so I took to Pdb to investigate:
(Pdb) p sub
_SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='action', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices={}, required=True, help=None, metavar=None)

While mypy is just fine with using argparse._SubParsersAction as type hint, this seems wrong to me given that usually the underscore denotes private API in Python, and relying on that for a type hint sounds like a bad idea.
So, how can I type hint such a parameter without relying on private API?

This question is similar to: Python: Private Types in Type Hints?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This module was written before typing was added to python.  This class is 'private' in the sense that you never instantiate it directly.  And it isn't imported with *.  add_argument also returns a 'private' object.

argparse._SubParsersAction is a subclass of public Action.

@hpaulj My concern is that since it's "private" it is not necessarily stable API and could as such change, e.g. get renamed. Is this a wrong assumption?

argparse changes at a glacial pace, with considerable concern about backward compatibilty.  I've followed development for years and can't think of a 'private' class that's been renamed. That said, there is an github issue about this name and typing, so it might be changed - in 5 years :)

Does any project ever call add_subparsers more than once? It might be simpler to ignore its return value, and only work with a single one of its bound methods, i.e. x = parser.add_subparsers().add_parser instead of x = parser.add_subparsers().

Or, note that the type returned by add_subarsers doesn't matter, only that it's something that implements a protocol that you could (tediously, but sticking to publicly documented features, safely) define yourself, something like class HasAddParser(Protocol): def add_parser(self, name: str, have: fun, with: this, ...): ...
